# USB stopped working

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, kernel

I use Ubuntu 14.04. Four days ago, the USB stopped working. Since keyboard and mouse are attached via USB, I could see the system booting but was unable to use it.

Power down has not helped. Booting from the same disk on a different computer shows the same problem. Booting another Linux on that computer works just fine.

Mounting the fixed disk on a different computer, I could read its dmesg file. Comparing that to the working machine, the first difference that sprang to mind was this:

bad (32-bit linux):
[ 1.301175] usb usb6: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[ 1.301177] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-30-generic ohci_hcd

and good (64-bit linux):
[ 1.233156] usb usb7: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[ 1.233158] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-66-generic ohci_hcd

So it seems that a software update caused the change.

Now my question:
how can I safely revert to the old driver manually, i.e., without using apt-get or any other automatisms?

Answer (score 0):

well I guess it stops working after a kernel upgrade, and I guess you have installed the kernel manually as Linux 3.19 is not the 14.04 official branch (it's 3.13)  so:

if you press the computer reset hardware button, the system should prompt the grub menu.
There, you can select the last kernel version with good usb support ,as in grub the usb is already managed by bios, by clicking 'advanced options'.

Doing this, you'll enter again in your GNU/Linux system, where either I'd remove this  Linux 3.19.0-30-generic , as it's not the official branch of ubuntu 14.04, or I'd try again but reading carefully documentation, installing firmware package, installing a newer one as 4.1 branch, etc.

I hope it helps.
cheers

Comment: Hi gentooza, 
thank you very much for your help. No, I didn't do a kernel upgrade, at least not knowingly, but I have done the normal Ubuntu software update.     
The computer had several USB connections (keyboard, mouse, printer, an external hard disk), of which everything but the hard disk stopped working.
I ended up installing the 64-bit version, from which I am typing this, but I kept the logs in case anyone cares. 
Cheers - kriz

Comment: ahhh ok! my version is 64 bits too, it's why I've the 3.13 branch too :-) (I thought it was the standard for ubuntu 14.04)
the usb driver is inside kernel, so If you have problems in future you'll simply have to choose the already tested old version linux by grub (the bootloader wich runs just after turning on the computer),and therefore downgrade the problematic kernel. (so in my point of view you'll have to use apt-get :-) )
cheers! Joa